# jquery empty inputs, radio buttons and selects in a div

Tags: jquery

With this jquery command i empty al the inputs in a div:

```
$('#afwijkende_prijzen_vak'+nexty).find('input:text').val('');
```

But the radio's and the select's keep the the selected value, how can i also reset this ones (Selects to the default first value, radio buttons empty)

Comment: What did you try? Did you google anything? What did you find?

Comment: with a .reset i reset the whole form, i only want to reset a part in a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selects and radios need to be handled differently than just .val(''). You need to use .prop('checked', false); for radio's -

```
.find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
```

and for the select lists you need to designate the first value like.

```
$('yourselectlist').val('firstitem');
```